Apache conditional proxy pass works partially
References
Apache Conditional Proxy pass
Issue
I want to implement a conditional proxy pass for the below scenario:
if the URL contains "gateway" like the URL below:
https://www.localhost.com.br/gateway/login

I want this URL to be proxied to a URL, without the word "gateway", with a different port like the URL below,
https://www.localhost:10094/login

If the URL doesnt contain "gateway" like the URL below:
https://www.localhost:10094/backend/users/list

The proxy pass I mentioned earlier should proxied to port 10095.

What works
The proxy works fine when theres not the word gateway.

Current issue
The proxy fails to work properly when there is the word gateway.
When the word gateway exists in the URL, the API gives out a 403 (Forbidden).
Im not understanding what is happening.
Code / solution attempt
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

ProxyPass /.well-known !
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^gateway [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://localhost:10094/$1 [QSA,P,L]
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://localhost:10095/$1 [P,L]
RewriteRule ^gateway/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:10095/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:10094/


Your question is unclear: do you want to implement a redirection or a proxy? It is either or, not both.

A proxy. Sorry for the confusion.
